# How to change folder separator and ~ character in p10k command line

Tags: zsh, powerline-statusline

In [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) (zsh) the path to branch separator can be a triangle or semicircle (bottom in image); in powerline (top of image), the "triangles" can separate also folder/subfolder instead of the `/`, is this achievable in p10k ?

I am using [Meslo LG S](https://github.com/romkatv/dotfiles-public/tree/master/.local/share/fonts/NerdFonts) as it is appropriate for p10k icons.

[image]

[External image of p10k prompt with /](https://www.warp.dev/blog/how-to-set-up-powerlevel10k-on-warp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `~/.p10k.zsh`:

```bash
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_OMIT_FIRST_CHARACTER=true
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_PATH_SEPARATOR=$' \uE0B1 '
```

Comment: for semicircle use \uE0B5 source: https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/issues/506

Answer (score 0):

To replace `~` with a home icon, add/uncomment this in `.p10k.zsh`. The second command is in line 355

```
  typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_HOME_FOLDER_ABBREVIATION=$'\uF015'
  typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_CLASSES=()
```